# Two boys grow up on same planet, trained by AI and Nature, ends with each battling each other with tech and magic

Tags: story-identification, novel

The plot of the book is two young men grow up (or end up?) on a planet. One discovered technology (in a cave) and an AI educates him how to use advanced tech. The other man is discovered by natural beings who teach him how to use magic based on nature or the earth. He ends up in a battle with the other man, pitting earth against tech.

A bit transparent plot wise but a book from my past that I'm keen to re-read.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233710/two-brothers-war-against-one-another-magic-vs-technology (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds a bit like Roger Zelazny's *Changeling* -- in which a wizard's son, Pol Detson, it switched with an engineer's son, who grows up as Mark Marakson.  The wizard's son is raised in a technological world, while the engineer's son becomes an inventor in the world of magic.  Eventually (in the second book, *Madwand*) Pol Detson finds a way back to the world of his birth, and Mark Marakson must find a way to stop him from picking up where his father, an evil and megalomanic wizard, left off.